# Hide page sections based on user role in Visual Composer

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to hide certain page sections based on user role in Visual Composer by adding Custom Content Shortcode in two text blocks. The first text block is at the top of the content I want to hide to all but admins and contains:

```
[is role=administrator]
```

The second text block, at the bottom of the content I want to hide, contains the closing tag,

```
[/is]
```

This is doing what it's supposed to and hiding the content, however, Visual Composer doesn't seem to like it, and VC shortcode winds up getting outputted to the page for admins, i.e. [/vc_column]. I can't get it to *not* display the VC shortcode. It's strange too that it only outputs the shortcode for admins.

If there is a different or better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm open to any solutions! I just want certain page sections to only be visible to admins.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the header function to use Jquery to remove the elements via css class for each user.

Below is not a tested solution but can be a way to achieve what you wanted but not sure how to remove completely the output source code only hide it.

This can be added to the function file or built into a plugin.

```
        function insert_header()
        {
           // Check what user role
           global $current_user;
           $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
           $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
           //return $user_role;
           // Check if the user has role
           if($user_role == "editor")
           { 
             // inject jQuery or css to remove the elements by class
           }


        }

        add_action('wp_head','insert_header');
```